# jquery ui autocomplete with delegate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, delegates

I have set up JQuery UI autocomplete according to the docs and it works for any input with class="tag-item" that is rendered to the page. However the user can add inputs into the dom via JS so I need a way to bind autocomplete to the new dynamically created inputs using delegate. I am not sure how to set this up, any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In my mind this solution smells, but I ended up just wrapping the code in a function and calling the function in the complete function after the new input is injected into the DOM. As far as I can tell I would have to alter the code for autocomplete to make it work with delegate. I am 100% sure there is a better way so that is why this is a comment and not an marked as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could delegate with a 'focusin' event to setup your input field.

[See this post](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/configuring-ui-widgets-and-interactions-with-live/)

Comment: @KrisF, you took the words right out of my mouth ... verbatim! :-(

Comment: The post is still available via archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20111124101453/http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/configuring-ui-widgets-and-interactions-with-live

Comment: Please at least post code snippets of the main points. urls on the interwebs aren't forever and ever.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, here's what I ended up using:

```
$('#some-container').delegate('input.to-autocomplete', 'focus', function(e) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: autocomplete_url
        /* etc, etc */
    });
});
$('#some-container').delegate('input.to-autocomplete', 'blur', function(e) {
    var target = $(this);
    if (target.hasClass('ui-autocomplete-input')) {
        target.autocomplete('destroy');
    }
});
```

My hope is that it will ease the burden on the browser since I'm autocompleting (possibly) hundreds of elements off and on, and the autocomplete result uls start stacking up otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

For me the following worked:

```
$('#autocomplete').on('focusin', 'input', function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a go at this but couldn't seem to make it work, here's my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/uGdm2/

Comment: just to add:  http://jsfiddle.net/uGdm2/3/ seems to be better than the version you quoted :)

Comment: I don't think it's better, no.

Comment: you had several errors:
http://jsfiddle.net/uGdm2/65/

javascript:void(0) works better than javascript:false
you missed a ) after the 1st function.
And you don't want to clone(true), try clone() and it won't clone events.