# JQuery: dialog doesn't fire autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog and http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete with JQuery 1.7.2 and JQuery-UI 1.8.18.

There is a form with a text box, which will fire the autocomplete fine when loaded in the page as normal. It's nice and simple!

```
(function() {

  jQuery(function($) {
    return $("#type").autocomplete({
      source: "/auto-suggest/supplies",
      minLength: 2
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

However, if the form is rendered via a dialog the autocomplete does not fire (no UI changes, and the server shows no access to the source url). I'm assuming this is because the input field has not been rendered at document load. So, I tried to use dialog's `create` event to assign the autocomplete, by passing the function to it as a callback. Again, the autocomplete does not fire.

I'm mystified as to how to get this to work. I would be tempted to get the dialog to create and then hide on document load, but in this instance there could be several instances of the  dialog as it's related to table data.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`open` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open) - this will ensure that the DOM elements are ready

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
  $("#type").autocomplete({
      source: "/auto-suggest/supplies",
      minLength: 2
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try delegate

[Delegate autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650737/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-delegate)

BEST SOLUTION IS WROTE BY: ManseUK

Answer (score 1):

You can even get the values and then in the success call dialog

```
$.get('/auto-suggest/supplies', function(data) {
  //call dialog here
});
```